# Can we grow a habit?

Tags: word-usage, collocations

What are verbs that we can use  in a collocation with the noun habit? Particularly, Is using "to grow" correct as in the following example sentence? Is it standard English?

> When people can realize that using the machine can be much more time-saving,
>   they will ***grow*** a habit to use it eventually.

I saw  in [Longman Dictionary](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/habit) that the verbs create,form,develop are used and make/get into the habit of doing something are more common patterns but I also saw many times that "growing  a habit" is used on the Internet.

Comment: _Grow/create/make_ a habit, or: _I'm turning the constant use of the machine into a habit_. In this sentence, it could be replaced for: _When people can realize that they can save more time by turning the frequent use of the machine into a habit._

Comment: Build, cultivate, inculcate, or nurture might work better than 'grow', to indicate the intention, will & repetition in addition to the continuity required.

Answer (score 8):

Usually a habit is **developed** over time, or an action **becomes** a habit.

> If one is not careful, *social smoking* can *become* a real smoking habit.

However, the first thing that came to mind with

> grow *(your)* habit

was that, with the legalization of marijuana, one might literally be able to

> grow one's habit

Answer (score 6):

"Grow a habit" is not idiomatic - as you mention, the usual verbs are create, form, and develop; or "get into **the** habit of...".

Any usage of "grow a habit" that you may have found on the Internet is not standard.  I speculate that somebody might use that language in advertising or marketing as a way to stand out and draw your attention.

I would not use that form.

Comment: Somehow I heard "to grow a habit" but as I said when I looked it up, I could not find any reference. I was wondering ,can we say that it does not sound non-idiomatic irritatingly, but strictly speaking it is wrong OR it does sound non-idiomatic when you hear it  at the first sight like a non-native speaker can talk?

Comment: I mean is it that common among native speakers?

Comment: I'm a native speaker (American) and I have never spoken or heard that phrase.  It would just sound weird to me - like a habit was a kind of plant that you were growing.

Comment: I see Thank you.The Internet can be misleading sometimes :)

Comment: Btw I noticed people use on the Internet it  like " to grow a habit of doing something"..they even created a pattern like "get into the habit of doing something"..:))

Comment: Am I the only one here who read the question title and immediately thought of [the kind of habit nuns wear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religious_habit#/media/File:Sisters_(Daughters_of_Mary)_Roman_Catholic_Singing.jpg)?

Comment: I think "grow a habit" might be common in Indian English.

Answer (score 5):

It's certainly possible to "grow" a habit but I would recommend a number of other verbs instead:

Active:

> make
>   acquire
>   develop
>   instill
>   inculcate
>   get

Passive:

> become
>   have
>   is

[Somewhat relevant Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=*_VERB+a+habit&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3).  Note most of these are past-tense since, presumably, you would have started on the habit in the past.

Comment: I would think it's worth noting that "inculcate" is not a common English word.

Comment: @Catija Absolutely -- but you so rarely get to use it in a sentence!  :)

Comment: I would add "cultivate" to the list. I have heard it used often, and it is similar in meaning to "grow".

Comment: Inculcate is a great word, but it's worth noting that the subject and object of that verb differ in common usage, whereas all of the others are somewhat reflexive. I develop my own habits. I inculcate habits in others.

Answer (score 3):

In standard English, one does not *grow* a habit. But one can grow *into* a habit, or grow  *out of* it. [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=grow%20into%20the%20habit%2C%20grow%20out%20of%20the%20habit&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgrow%20into%20the%20habit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgrow%20out%20of%20the%20habit%3B%2Cc0) shows that both phrases have declined substantially from their peaks, though. I was surprised to learn that "grow into a habit" was so much more common than the opposite phrase; I have heard "grow out of the habit" in use much more often.

For your specific situation, however, "grow into the habit" doesn't seem right, as growing into a habit doesn't take voluntary effort whereas using a machine does. I think "habituated" would work better. The contrast between the two can be shown by this sentence:

> Since I stopped working, I've grown into the habit of staying up
>   really late, but I'm trying to habituate myself to an earlier
>   bedtime again.

You could also try "grow *accustomed* to using" instead of "grow the habit of using"*.

Answer (score 1):

The most direct answer to your question is **no.** That sentence would be understood - it isn't completely nonsensical - but it certainly isn't standard. I've never once heard a native speaker use it. You are correct that *get in the habit* or *make it a habit* are most often used.

**Original Sentence:**

> When people can realize that using the machine can be much more
>   time-saving, they will **grow** a habit to use it eventually.

**Modified Sentences:**

> 1) When people realize that the machine saves them time, they will eventually **get in the habit of using it**.
>
> 2) When people realize that the machine saves them time, they will eventually **make a habit of using it**.
>
> 3) When people realize that the machine saves them time, they will eventually **make using it a habit**.
>
> 4) When people realize that the machine saves them time, **using it** will eventually **become a habit**.

I will admit that the first three "patterns" are tricky. Tricky enough that I don't know if I would call them patterns - maybe they're idioms or figures of speech. Using them this way (unless someone can point out a counterexample) applies to the word **habit** only.

There are other phrases you could use- a person can **pick up** or **fall into** or **acquire** a habit. They could also **develop** a habit over time. However, for the sentence you asked about, the above examples work best.